# what is the best way to implement right shift with signed number through verilog?

Tags: verilog, hardware, fpga

I'm trying to implement a piece of C code like this:

```
if (test_num>0)
    result = (test_num + offset) >> coeff;
else
    result = -((offset - test_num) >> coeff);
```

in order to implement this, I did design as this:

```
assign abs_result = test_num > signed(0) ? result : -result;

always @(*)
    case (coeff)
      4'd0: abs_result_tmp = abs_result;
      4'd1: abs_result_tmp = {1'b0, abs_result[7:1]};
      4'd2: abs_result_tmp = {2'b0, abs_result[7:2]};
      .....
      default: ...
    endcase

assign final_result = test_num > signed(0) ? abs_result_tmp : -abs_result_tmp;
```

because I need to finish this function as soon as possible, I won't be able to use registers for this function. Only combination logic is permitted. Is my verilog implementation for this C code the most quick one? Or is there any other better solution to improve timing? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to define the type as as signed and use >>>.

Alternative is to repeat the MS bit: (There can be typos!)

```
case (coef)
4'd0 : result = test_num[7:0];
4'd1 : result = {test_num[7],test_num[7:1]};
4'd2 : result = {{2{test_num[7]}},test_num[7:2]};
4'd3 : result = {{3{test_num[7]}},test_num[7:3]};
..
endcase

// This would be nice but I don't think it is allowed: {{coef{test_num[7]}},test_num[7:coef]};
```

---

You want  -1>>1 to become zero. What your are actually doing is not signed shifting but shifting and then rounding. In C -1 >> 1 will also be -1. (As such your title is somewhat misleading. :-) That is fine as there are many ways to round numbers. But beware that there will be discrepancies if you C-code and Verilog code use different schemes. (Lookup bankers rounding).

Comment: Hi oldfart, I don't think repeat MS bit is right. You see, "-1" will be represented as 0xff, when you right shift one bit, "-1" should be 0. But if you repeat MS bit, this "-1" will always be "-1"

Comment: Hi oldfart, i'm sorry I misunderstand your reply. yes you are right if you defined the type as signed and use >>>, as this post explained: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132773/difference-between-and-in-verilog/134062. Thanks.

Comment: Hi oldfart, I just tried to run simulation with type defined as signed and use ">>>". most simulation seems ok but it failed with test_num= -1. The simulation outputs -1 when right shift 1 bit. This seems not right. So I think my original code is right. I don't know if there are other "reasonable" code which could be more "quick" when implemented in backend design (I mean synthesis and layout). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Classical verilog does not support signed numbers and will not do signed compare for you. Though negative numbers are naturally represented by 2-compliment cod and will have the uppper bit set to '1'. Supposedly your tes_num is 32 bit, than you can always test test_num[31] for negativity. The rest should work as in 'c', provided your sizes of result and offset are the same:

```
input  [31:0] test_num;
reg [31:0] result, offset;    
always @*
  if (test_num[31] == 0) //positive numbers
    result = (test_num + offset) >> coeff;
  else
    result = -((offset - test_num) >> coeff);
```

Comment: Hi Serge, the problem is that if the test_num is "-1", then this piece of code doesn't work. that is the reason why I change test_num from signed to "abs" first and changed to signed again. In fact, in modern simulatin, such as irun it supports signed simulation